# Example of drag n drop in AIR

Tags: air

I am looking for a simple example of Drag-n-drop within a webpage(say dragging a image to a tabel cell), in AIR (using AIR api)
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may find something [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.1/devappshtml/WS6717AA0A-2B7D-4728-86DC-7D60F919E6B4.html), [here](https://admin.adobe.acrobat.com/_a227210/p48882098/) or, best of all, [Bulgaria Flex Group](http://groups.google.com/group/flexbulgaria/browse_thread/thread/0910170142c91c08) where the entry begins with "I would like to show an easy way to drag and drop files from filesystem within your Air applications."

Hmmm ... just read your request again and I realise it's not quite what you asked for. I hope the DND of files at least points you in the right direction.